# Is it possible to disable "xyz is slowing down the game" popups in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it possible to disable "xyz is slowing down the game" popups in Starcraft 2? If so, how?

Comment: For a detailed explanation of exactly what this message means, see [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65049/65763#65763).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a regular basis, you shouldn't see this popup much...

This occurs when a person has a slow computer, too high settings or connectivity issues.

It's a game mechanic that can't be changed, if it occurs too much the problem might be on your side.

Comment: I like that your score is 1337. :) -- On topic, I wouldn't mind it so much if the popup disappeared without me having to click the X. *Currently searching registry settings.*

Comment: It's unlikely to be in the register, you might want to try to look through the MPQ files (there exists software to see and alter them) to see if a setting is there but it would be rare. Your best bet is to try to ask Blizzard to include an option for it... Well, I'm a bit unsure but I think it disappears when the problem is resolved. But if you have a friend/opponent that has the problem the whole game, yeah... :-(