# How long is StarCraft 2's typical input delay compared to other competitive games?

Tags: starcraft-2, dota-2, heroes-of-newerth

Battle.net 2.0 seems to have severe netcode issues, meaning that commands take longer to be executed than they should. This is likely a result of preventing lag and dropped connections, but it comes at the cost of performance. Compared to games like Heroes of Newerth, Dota2, and Counter-Strike which have excellent latency, how long is StarCraft 2's delay?

There was a video done on this when SC2 first came out years ago but it's woefully out of date now; patches have supposedly fixed this, but the SC2 is still clearly slower than Brood War iCCup #LL. A simple example of this cross-comparison analysis between games can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0YQP4TQdsA), but I don't know how to replicate it.

Is anyone capable of repeating the experiment for SC2 and possibly for other games as well?

Comment: iirc starcraft 2 has an inbuilt delay of 200ms (that is if your lag is 50ms, your command will take a total of 200ms to begin, if your lag is 300ms, your command will take 300ms to begin). if I find a link that confirms this i'll post it as an answer, with a clearer explanation.

Comment: It may be worth editing the question to reduce the scope. Perhaps, just ask about the input delay for Starcraft 2, and create new questions if you want information on input delay for other games.

Comment: Not sure why this would get downvoted; every game has a very small delay between when you click the mouse physically and when the action is executed in game. It will vary game-to-game based on your framerate and how the game is designed with respect to frames and multiplayer synchronization. But there's no way this is as high as 200ms; that would make most micro impossible. I think of it like a MIDI keyboard; delays of only 30ms make it impossible to play. Comfortable is <10ms. Whatever the delay is, it's vastly shorter than network latency.

Comment: Oh wait you're asking about the total latency including network? If that's the case, there's no way to answer this. There are many bnet servers in many locations, nuances in the match-making system, etc. It sounds like you just want to complain in the form of a question, to which the answer is just to say what that youtube video says.

Comment: @tenfour there is clearly a way to answer this as both of the videos that I've linked to have done so. The problem is that the video for SC2 is nearly two years old and changes have been made since.

Comment: @chobok The delay for other games are already in the linked videos. If you have a source for that number for SC2 I'd love to see it. People throw around various values but I never find anything to corroborate them.

Comment: @chobok: That's somewhat correct, though it's actually the largest ping between *any* two players that matters.  See my answer for (lots) more details.

Comment: You have no proof any delay that exists is due to *poor* netcode and isn't simply on purpose.  If it is such a problem why are all the professional SC2 players not complaining about it?

Comment: @Ramhound It may be on purpose, and if it's on purpose I'm perfectly okay with still calling it poor. Many professional players have mentioned it in the past- that's one of the reasons why the above videos even exist. It's not an enormous problem because players are used to playing with lag due to inter-region play and never became accustomed to playing with low latency. It was the same way in SC1 until it was made possible to play with "LAN latency" online, after which it immediately became tournament standard.

Answer (score 28):

Understanding why this question is somewhat meaningless requires an understanding of how Starcraft 2's network architecture works.

In most online games, you have a server and a number of clients.  Every client will send all of its actions to the server, and the server will send the result of all those actions to every client.  The server is the *authority* - the state of the game-world in the server's memory is the way the game-world "actually looks" at that moment.  A client's game-world, however, is always out-of-date, because there is some latency *(about one half of the [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping#Other_types_of_pinging))* between when the server sends out updates and the client receives them.  To combat this, the game will attempt to [guess the real positions of objects](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking#Lag_compensation).  Keeping the game [smooth when it guesses wrong](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking#Entity_interpolation) is complicated, and [more work](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking#Input_prediction) must be done to account for latency in the other direction.  In short, it's complicated.

However, this is not how Starcraft II's networking works.

---

The primary problem with the client-server model is that every server-tick *(usually about 20 times a second)*, we need to send out the new position/velocity/health/etc. of every object that's changed.  This is fine in a game like Counterstrike, where you might have upwards of 60 players and maybe a few physics-entities to update every tick.  However, in an RTS like Starcraft II, where an 8-player game could easily have over 1000 units, this is simply not feasible.

Instead, Starcraft II *(and every other mainstream RTS)* takes a different approach.  The idea is that the game should be completely deterministic, so that running the game with **exactly** the same inputs should always produce exactly the same results.  Then all we need to do is make sure all players run the same inputs at the same time, and they should all see the same results.  SCII does this by queuing up every command you give it to be done at some point in the future *(typically, around 12 frames ie. 200ms)*.  Everyone sends their commands to everyone else and then, when everyone has everyone's commands, everyone executes them all at once.  Now instead of syncing thousands of units, the players only need a sync a handful of commands, a *huge* improvement.  And because there is no need for a central authority, RTS games (including SCII) will usually just have players communicate directly with each other, rather than have a central-server.  This sort of networking architecture is called **peer-to-peer (P2P)**.

---

There are a number of problems with this peer-to-peer architecture:

- **Observable "lag"**.  Because commands are queued and not executed immediately, there is an observable lag between when a player clicks the mouse and when the unit responds.  This "lag" is not lag in the traditional sense, in that it is *not* due to the latency between players; rather, it is a fundamental and unavoidable consequence of how SCII's networking architecture works.  It is *not* due to poor coding on Blizzard's part - there is nothing they can do to avoid it without switching to a client-server architecture *(which would have its own, more severe issues; see above)*
- **Every player is as slow as the slowest player.**  If the 200ms queue-time has passed and one player still hasn't sent out their latest commands, the game will freeze for everyone until everyone receives that player's commands.  In SCII, after about one second of not receiving any commands from a player it will display the *"waiting for player XXX"* dialog.  Also, when SCII detects that a player is consistently running behind on sending out their commands, the game will increase the queue-time to give the slower player more leeway.  **This is what the *"XXX is slowing down the game"* message means.**

  It's also why, when there is a laggy player, your units will take longer to respond to you, and why units will move slower or sometimes freeze altogether, even if your computer is more-than-capable of handling that many units.

  Finally, it's also why I said your question is "somewhat meaningless" - it's not that SCII has *"netcode issues,"* it's just that SCII has no choice but to increase the queue time, to compensate for the player not sending out commands fast enough.  This is unavoidable, and every mainstream RTS has this same problem *(Note that Counterstrike is client-server; and, due to not having as many units as an RTS, there is a good chance that HoN is client-server as well.  Client-server games will not have this issue at all.)*
- **Desyncs are possible**.  Under client-server, desyncing (that is, having a different game-state than everyone else) is not a problem, since the game is essentially *always* desynced, and always trying to compensate for it.  However, in a P2P RTS game, since there is no actual authority, a desync is catastrophic - how do we know whose game-state is correct!?  SCII is coded well enough that desyncs are exceedingly rare, and it will try its best to recover *(eg. if two players agree and one doesn't, you can be pretty sure the two players have the correct state)*, but sometimes that is simply not possible.  In SCII, this results with everyone being kicked from the game with the message "You have been desynced."
- **Cheating**.  In a client-server game, it's possible to give each client only the information it needs.  In a P2P game, however, in order to run the entire simulation, every player must know the *entire* game-state at all times.  This is why maphacks are possible in SCII - if the game were client-server, maphacks would be impossible.  Also, players can lie about who won/lost a game *(see "Stats Tracking" below)*.  These facts are the reason many people are talking about making RTS games client-server in the future, as users' bandwidth goes up.  All mainstream RTS's are still P2P, however.
- **Scaling**.  In a P2P game, the total amount of network traffic goes up quadratically with the number of players, unlike a client-server game where network traffic goes up linearly.  What this means is, while P2P requires less traffic for a small number of players, it requires much more for a large number of players.  You will probably never see a 64-player P2P game.

This list of drawbacks is why client-server is so much more popular.  However, for games with a large number of objects (primarily RTS's), these drawbacks are not nearly as bad as trying to sync thousands of units per update.

For more info on P2P games, see the canonical article that essentially made networked RTS's possible, [1500 Archers on a 28.8: Network Programming in Age of Empires and Beyond](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3094/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php)

---

**[Edit]**  There has been some confusion about the purpose of Battle.Net - after all, if there is no central server, why do we need Battle.Net?  Battle.Net serves a few purposes:

- **Matchmaking**.  The players communicate directly with each other in-game, but they need some way of discovering each other to begin with.
- **Stats tracking**.  Keeping track of wins/losses/achievements/etc.  Of course, since the game is not actually running on Blizzard's servers, Blizzard must rely on each player honestly reporting when they win/lose, which could lead to cheating.  But this sort of cheat is easy to detect, since two players disagreeing on a win or loss should be rare, and when it happens to the same player over and over...
- **[Nat Punch-through](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)**.  This is why you don't need to open any ports in your firewall to play Starcraft II.
- **Anti-piracy**.  There is no technical reason why the game should quit when Battle.Net goes down for repairs; or why you should need an Internet connection to play single-player.  They only do this as an *(misguided, in my opinion)* attempt to combat piracy.

Some people have claimed that, while the game is not actually *run* on Battle.Net's servers, the commands players send to each other are still routed through Battle.Net.  This is possible, but **highly** unlikely:  it would unnecessarily and enormously increase Blizzard's bandwidth costs, and increase the lag *(possibly significantly)* for all players.  The only benefit would be to hide the players' IP-addresses from each other.  I'll come back to this post when I learn more.

Comment: This info might or might not be true for Starcraft 2. But this 12 fram or 200ms stuff is not correct. You make it sound as if this value depends on the players in the game, but it does not. Try this: Open Marine Micro in your World Editor and play, afterwards open a "single player" Battle.net game with Marine Micro. You will notice a huge difference and it has nothing to do with your P2P stuff as there is no other player. The point is Battle.net forces this delay. Prove me wrong.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Starcraft 1 has almost the same amount of information floating through the network and iccup has way lower latency. The graphics might be crappy but the production / damage calculation needs similar inputs from all players.

Comment: Thanks for the level of detail. My only problem with this answer is that StarCraft 1 simply didn't have this issue and so I don't understand why SC2 does. People were able to play online SC1 with very good response times (either through a modified Battle.net like iCCup or by using 3rd party programs like Chaos Launcher). Your argument is that it's not feasible to run a P2P structure like this, and yet a game nearly 15 years old is capable of it. The differences between RTS architecture and that used in games like DotA helps clarify slightly, but that issue remains.

Comment: @Decency:  Those modified launchers likely just reduce the time between command executions, so that commands are executed much sooner after you give them.  This is obviously only a good idea if you can guarantee you'll have low latency to every other player.  My argument was that it's not feasible to run SC1/2 as a client-server, which still stands; those alternate clients do not change the fact that SC is P2P *(doing so would require a **complete** rewrite of the game, from the ground-up)*.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Right, which is perhaps now how you can understand my claim that SC2 has poor netcode. Even something as simple as TCP has a period where it determines what the connection is capable of; and even StarCraft 1 allowed you to modify the interval of "command executions" through the latency setting. I'm not advocating a client-server architecture, merely a P2P architecture that can correctly utilize the resources available to it.

Comment: @ayckoster: No, it is true of SCII, and the queued command stuff is correct (that's what the *"XXX is slowing down the game"* message means - the queue-time has been increased because someone isn't sending updates fast enough).  And I don't see what your example has to do with anything, other than showing that SCII queues commands in multiplayer mode, even if you're the only player there.

Comment: I might grab the SCII demo and take a tcpdump of the network traffic it generates, if it lets you do multiplayer - you'd probably see spikes of outgoing packets on a 200 ms period, it would make for a neat graph.

Comment: SC2 only uses TCP if UDP is disabled, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score -2):

Starcraft 2 has an input delay of 200 ms, like Starcraft 1 (Battle.net) [Reference](http://www.sk-gaming.com/content/33188-The_Lag_Monster). This is not due to the *netcode* but the servers force this delay to make it more competative.

This example goes for every server / client layout, even if the server is a client (player):

This delay is forced to make the game more balanced. Suppose I live next to the servers and you live on the other end of the country. I have a super good connection as I live in a big city and your connection is poor because there are no good providers where you live. My delay is 10 ms and yours is 190 ms.

While I cannot prove how the games are hosted or what network engine Blizzard uses it should suffice to say there is a set lower bound. Have you ever tried to play 1v1 with a buddy in the very same room? I mean even the worst possible netcode / network transfer with as many units as the game is possible to support should be nothing compared to 1 gigabit Ethernet.

If there is some kind of P2P GSL should have no lag as everybody is on the same switch (connected to the internet). Well, they still have lag issues.

The same is true if one player is selected to be host, they are still on the same subnet, so there should still be no delay.

In *other* games, say HoN, I would have a huge advantage, because my delay would be significantly lower than yours. Starcraft 2 tries to compensate this by forcing 200 ms delay. If your delay is bigger then that it's your problem and you have to suffer the consequences.

There is no point in comparing the delays as you cannot go below 200 ms, at least not in Battle.net.

iccup circumvented the 200 ms Starcraft 1 delay by providing an own server (not Battle.net) without Blizzards consent, this worked fine because there no policies and the game was pretty old, so Blizzard accepted it. But now there are hefty fines for reverse engineering the Battle.net.

During Beta [DarkBliz](http://darkblizz.org) tried to hack the Battle.net and the founder got threatened with law suits and backed of.

So basically there will not be a no/low delay version of Starcraft 2 until Blizzards says so. Please do not think that Blizzard implemented a poor *netcode*. I mean they are a multi-billion dollar company and if they wanted Starcraft 2 to have a smaller delay they would hire the right people if they do not already have them.

Here are the facts dictated by logic:

- There must be a **lower** bound for latency, no Starcraft 2 game can go below that. It might be 200 ms, as many sources *suggest* this value and this is the confirmed value for Starcraft 1. (See reasoning above)
- Blizzard must have their own reasons for this forced delay, as they have introduced this delay in every RTS they have released *and* every RTS was very popular.
- Even if you knew their code or software design is flawed (read bad) you cannot change that.

Comment: *"the servers force this delay to make it more competitive"* - this is not true.  The delay is due to the way network communications work in SC2 and all other RTS games.  I'll write up a more detailed answer later.

Comment: This new edit has even more misinformation.  SCII does **not** use a client-server architecture - like all mainstream RTS games, it uses P2P, which is *completely* different.  See my answer for more info.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Do you even understand my reasoning? I do not argue that there is a client/server architecture. I just state there must be some communication with the server, as a pure P2P with 2 players and 1 observer in the same subnet should have NO delay, but there is. Please provide either REAL proof that SC2 does not communicate with the Blizzard servers or at least try to reason. :) Because what you do now is just BS. You can even test your claim: Get 2 PCs in the same network, initiate a SC2 game, kill the internet connection. You should still be able to play.

Comment: The delay between issuing a command and the unit responding to it has **nothing to do with the latency between players**.  Please see my answer for the reason why, with references.

Comment: This is BS. Play a solo game, you have no latency. And if your queue is dynamically adjusted to the latency, then there should be none!!!!! Please think before arguing.

Comment: @Ayckoster the game doesn't dynamically adjust to your latency, it just uses a flat value as a minimum threshold. That's the whole issue to begin with.

Comment: @Ayckoster though you're also correct. Playing a single player game in multiplayer will cause you to have lag.

Comment: The problem with having no minimum queue-time is that even a small network hiccup will cause the game to completely freeze for everyone - and intermittently freezing completely causes a MUCH worse experience for players than having a little bit of command-lag.  Keep in mind that the minimum-delay (200ms) is still less than the average human reaction time (about [215 ms](http://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime/stats.php)), so it's really not that bad.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That's been clear for quite some time. SC1 mods detected and set this threshold in some fashion, often as low as ~30ms. It had minimal hiccups. This is an absolutely enormous difference in any sort of micro situation. Playing a micro intense game with that kind of latency is nearly impossible, which is one contributor behind why SC2 right now is so macro-heavy.

Comment: btw. the part about SC1 is wrong too. SC1 on bnet has around 450ms delay by default. With modifications it's typically reduced to 200ms, which coresponds to LAN. So SC1 pro games always had 200ms latency. While modifications can go a bit below that, that rarely works smoothly over the internet. Even singleplayer has around 100ms delay.

Comment: "iccup circumvented the 200 ms Starcraft 1 delay by providing an own server" That's nonsense too. ICCup having their own server is unrelated to latency. SC1 gameplay is entirely p2p. It's their client that reduces the latency.

Comment: @BlueRaja SC2 is p2p in the sense that every client simulates a full independent copy of the game. But game commands are relayed through blizzard servers. This is unlike SC1 where messages where p2p. 200ms delay is fine but noticeable if you pay attention.

Comment: @CodesInChaos:  *"But game commands are relayed through blizzard servers"* - Not that I don't trust your expertise, but do you have a source for this?  I've heard both this and the opposite claimed, but no one has any sources to cite.  And that way of doing it seems less reasonable - routing the traffic of every game through Blizzard's servers seems like a pretty big burdon on both Blizzard and the gamers *(increased ping)*, with no real benefit to either *(besides hiding clients' IP addresses from each other)*.

Comment: I'm no expert on SC2, only on SC1. The advantages of routing through the server are pretty big. Clients don't need to forward ports, which was a huge pain in SC1. It also prevents some kinds of disconnect hack. The traffic shouldn't be that big either, since you only transmit user commands, and not the game-state. All observations I heard fit with it. 1) Latency depends on the server you play on (many sources) 2) SC2 doesn't have incoming connections (source: R1CH) 3) You don't need to forward ports 4) R1CH [claims it's routed p2p](http://teamliquid.net/forum/viewpost.php?post_id=5116932)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: You don't need to forward ports in either SC1 or SC2.  Battle.Net provides simple [NAT punch-through](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) *(see above)* - this is also the reason you don't need to forward ports for things like Hamachi or Skype.  That has nothing to do with whether the traffic is routed through a server.  Also, the latency depending on the server is simply due to the fact that most other players on that server are from that part of the world!  Finally, that link to R1CH is what everyone links to, but he has no source or evidence for that claim.